# SQL Using count and sum when joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

When I try to join 2 tables and use SUM or COUNT it all works perfectly and as expected. However when I join 3 tables SUM and COUNT makes no sense because the JOIN statements create extra rows for each table to have a unique row so they over count and over sum the required values.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT PO_club.clubid, PO_club.name, PO_club.pic, PO_club.points, count(PO_club_user.userid), SUM(PO_club_point_log.points)
FROM PO_club 
INNER JOIN PO_club_user ON PO_club.clubid = PO_club_user.clubid 
LEFT JOIN PO_club_point_log ON PO_club.clubid = PO_club_point_log.clubid 
WHERE PO_club.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY PO_club.clubid 
ORDER BY PO_club.points DESC;
```

If I run two separate scripts like first join only `PO_club and PO_club_user` to get `COUNT()` it works. And then `run PO_club JOIN PO_club_point_log` to get `SUM()` its all good. However, I need to run it one script so that i would not need to sort it at the front end. Is there a way to `join 3 tables` and somehow `COUNT()` just work on `PO_club and PO_club_users` while `SUM` only on `PO_club and PO_club_point_log`?

Thanks!

Comment: If a club has no users, you don't want to output the club as in `INNER JOIN PO_club_user ON PO_club.clubid = PO_club_user.clubid`?

Comment: Much better to show your table schema and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

How's this? This will include all PO_clubs even if they don't have any users in case they have points. If that's not what you want, change the first `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT PO_club.clubid, PO_club.name, PO_club.pic, PO_club.points, count(PO_club_user.userid), t.sum_points
FROM PO_club
LEFT JOIN PO_club_user ON PO_club.clubid = PO_club_user.clubid
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PO_club_point_log.clubid, SUM(PO_club_point_log.points) AS sum_points
FROM PO_club_point_log INNER JOIN PO_club ON PO_club_point_log.clubid = PO_club.clubid
GROUP BY PO_club_point_log.clubid) AS t
ON PO_club.clubid = t.clubid
WHERE PO_club.deleted = 0
GROUP BY PO_club.clubid
ORDER BY PO_club.points DESC
```